# How To Install MariaDB 10.2.9.tar.gz on CentOS-7

Tags: linux, wordpress, mariadb, centos7, lamp

Please, I have CentOS 7 build in my environment and I want to install MariaDB-10 upwards as it is the recommended version for wordpress database. I can not access internet from the server to avoid security issues since the server is being hosted in my office and not on the domain.

Currently, I have MariaDB-5.5 install as part of the LAMP installation package but I am unable to import my database from my local machine unless I change the export to a particular version. I don't want to change the export version because I am not sure of what issues might surface in the future because of that. So, I am trying to install the MariaDB-10.2.9.tar.gz that I downloaded but I have not been able to do so with the instructions that I have seen online.

Your great help will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use package: http://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/centos/7.3/x86_64/rpms/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please guide me on how to use the rpm?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not able to access the internet directly from your database server, download the rpm packages from the repository link provided by Ipor Sircer. Here is a pretty good documentation about the necessary packages and installation with rpm: [installing-mariadb-with-the-rpm-tool](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-with-the-rpm-tool/)

Comment: sorry, copy the downloaded rpms on a USB stick or similar and put them on your database server